# opengl rotate tangent to a circle

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have an object right now which I have moving in a circle around the vertical (Y) axis. I want to *rotate this object so it is always aligned with the tangent of the circle*, how do I do this? Not sure what combination of sin/cosine/tan to use as the first argument of glRotatef...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `glRotatef` is the angle, in radians (so 0 is no rotation, PI is flipped around end for end, and 2*PI is rotated all the way back to the original orientation).

You probably could have answered this yourself through trial and error in less time than it took to askk the question.

Note that if you choose the center of rotation to be the center of the circle instead of the center of the object, you won't need a separate translation step.

Comment: please read the question more carefully. I was asking what value to pass in as the first argument if I want the object to rotate in an angle tangential to the circle

Comment: You don't use any of `sin`, `cos`, or `tan`.  The angle is the argument to those functions.  Whatever angle you previously passed to `sin` and `cos` when computing the displacement, is the angle you should pass to `glRotatef`.  `glRotatef` will internally use `sin` and `cos` as necessary.

Comment: Turns out I was making it a lot more complicated then it needed to be. Initially I was doing circular motion by using

glTranslatef(4*f,0,4*g) where f and g were sin and cos functions of time.

It turns out you can just use a translate and a rotate to get the same effect, and the rotation will always be tangent to the circle

glRotatef(10*TIME,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(0,0,5);